# Invalid write on sizeof

Tags: c++, c++11, valgrind, realsense

[image]

How can Valgrind say this:

```
==13233== Thread 4:
==13233== Invalid write of size 4
==13233==    at 0x13AC1F: Server::listener_thread() (realsense_multicam.cpp:136)
==13233==    by 0x4E456DA: start_thread (pthread_create.c:463)
==13233==    by 0x98F471E: clone (clone.S:95)
==13233==  Address 0x1377d938 is 1,192 bytes inside a block of size 1,256 free'd
==13233==    at 0x4C3323B: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==13233==    by 0x14A96F: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<Server>::deallocate(Server*, unsigned long) (new_allocator.h:125)
==13233==    by 0x149489: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<Server> >::deallocate(std::allocator<Server>&, Server*, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:462)
==13233==    by 0x1476AB: std::_Vector_base<Server, std::allocator<Server> >::_M_deallocate(Server*, unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:180)
==13233==    by 0x145B3B: void std::vector<Server, std::allocator<Server> >::_M_realloc_insert<Server&>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Server*, std::vector<Server, std::allocator<Server> > >, Server&) (vector.tcc:448)
==13233==    by 0x143974: void std::vector<Server, std::allocator<Server> >::emplace_back<Server&>(Server&) (vector.tcc:105)
==13233==    by 0x13B514: main (realsense_multicam.cpp:272)
==13233==  Block was alloc'd at
==13233==    at 0x4C3217F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==13233==    by 0x14A9DE: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<Server>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:111)
==13233==    by 0x14951C: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<Server> >::allocate(std::allocator<Server>&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:436)
==13233==    by 0x1478FB: std::_Vector_base<Server, std::allocator<Server> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:172)
==13233==    by 0x145A05: void std::vector<Server, std::allocator<Server> >::_M_realloc_insert<Server&>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Server*, std::vector<Server, std::allocator<Server> > >, Server&) (vector.tcc:406)
==13233==    by 0x143974: void std::vector<Server, std::allocator<Server> >::emplace_back<Server&>(Server&) (vector.tcc:105)
==13233==    by 0x13B514: main (realsense_multicam.cpp:272)
```

sizeof(serv_storage) is not writing anything right?

And then, on line 137, it says:

```
==13167== Invalid read of size 4
==13167==    at 0x13AC43: Server::listener_thread() (realsense_multicam.cpp:137)
==13167==    by 0x4E456DA: start_thread (pthread_create.c:463)
==13167==    by 0x98F471E: clone (clone.S:95)
==13167==  Address 0x1378b828 is 1,256 bytes inside a block of size 2,512 free'd
==13167==    at 0x4C3323B: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==13167==    by 0x14A96F: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<Server>::deallocate(Server*, unsigned long) (new_allocator.h:125)
==13167==    by 0x149489: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<Server> >::deallocate(std::allocator<Server>&, Server*, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:462)
==13167==    by 0x1476AB: std::_Vector_base<Server, std::allocator<Server> >::_M_deallocate(Server*, unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:180)
==13167==    by 0x145B3B: void std::vector<Server, std::allocator<Server> >::_M_realloc_insert<Server&>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Server*, std::vector<Server, std::allocator<Server> > >, Server&) (vector.tcc:448)
==13167==    by 0x143974: void std::vector<Server, std::allocator<Server> >::emplace_back<Server&>(Server&) (vector.tcc:105)
==13167==    by 0x13B514: main (realsense_multicam.cpp:274)
==13167==  Block was alloc'd at
==13167==    at 0x4C3217F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==13167==    by 0x14A9DE: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<Server>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:111)
==13167==    by 0x14951C: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<Server> >::allocate(std::allocator<Server>&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:436)
==13167==    by 0x1478FB: std::_Vector_base<Server, std::allocator<Server> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:172)
==13167==    by 0x145A05: void std::vector<Server, std::allocator<Server> >::_M_realloc_insert<Server&>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Server*, std::vector<Server, std::allocator<Server> > >, Server&) (vector.tcc:406)
==13167==    by 0x143974: void std::vector<Server, std::allocator<Server> >::emplace_back<Server&>(Server&) (vector.tcc:105)
==13167==    by 0x13B514: main (realsense_multicam.cpp:274)
```

the relevant code in Server:

```
class Server {

    public:
        Server(int port);
        void * listener_thread();
        void init_listener_thread();
        void update_buffer(const unsigned char * data, int offset, unsigned long numbytes);

    private:
        int init_sock, conn_sock;
        char * send_buffer;
        int buffer_size = 1024;
        char receive_buffer[1024];
        struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
        struct sockaddr_storage serv_storage;
        socklen_t addr_size;
        pthread_mutex_t buffer_access_mutex;
        pthread_t listener_thread_id;
        unsigned long frame_size;
};
```

Comment: I tried to help you by pasting your image into my IDE.  Unfortunately, my IDE can't convert images to code. :-(

Answer (score 5):

The valgrind output tells us that while calling `emplace_back` on a `std::vector<Server>`, the vector ran out of capacity and had to `_M_realloc_insert`, that is, reallocate memory and move all its objects over to the new buffer.

I suspect you are holding a reference/pointer to a `Server` that lives inside your vector, which was invalidated when the vector deleted the old capacity buffer.
You should be careful with references/pointer or iterators to vectors that you intend to extend. Hold an index instead.

Comment: I think I see the problem. The code [at the link share above](https://gist.github.com/richardrl/aa0fe77c10606cbf873a65c349a07bc7#file-realsense_multicam-cpp-L249) makes a copy of the `Server` instance as it stores it into the vector - which there's an active thread running on it!  Suggestion: Create instances of `Storage` off the heap (i.e "new" it) and store it as a vector of pointers.

Comment: If you absolutely need to use pointers, use `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique` or `std::shared_ptr` or `std::make_shared`, not raw pointers.

Comment: "You should be careful with references/pointer or iterators to vectors that you intend to extend. Hold an index instead." I don't think I held a reference? If you look at the code link, what I did was index into the realsense_server_arr later on, but didn't hold onto any Server's created in the initial for loop

Comment: I have temporarily fixed the error by running a *second* for loop to run the init_listener_thread() for each Server, but still not sure 1) what the actual problem with my previous code was and 2) what is the best way to structure my intended logic

Answer (score 1):

Best guess:

Your code is deleting the instance of Server before ending the thread running inside `Server::listener_thread`

Comment: What does it mean to "delete" the server? I'm not really familiar cause my expertise is python

Comment: the Server objects are being stored in an array, and then i call "update_buffer" on them later